# Rails block user account if failed test during registration process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to build User registration flow where user signup to the blog_app and after account confirmation (via email link) he/she will be able to log in but have no ability to access their posts if he/she doesn't pass Legal Test (after the User account is confirmed, they should be presented with the Legal Test before they can do anything else, user needs to pass the test only once).
For authentication I'm using Devise gem.

I'm wondering should I use some Devise build-in module such case? or should I create additional DB column in Users table with status e.g. `status: 'passed'` or `status: 'faild'` and use pundit policy to block access in case User didn't passed the Legal Test?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should an authorization gem like Pundit to manage authorization.

To accomplish something like this in Devise you would need separate roles for a "passed user" and a "failed user". It will quickly get messy and confusing as it's really not what it's meant for.

Using an authorization gem like Pundit is the way to go for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will have to add a new column like `status` where you store the status and then override the devise's `active_for_authentication?` method so that the user is not allowed to login if he/she is marked as failed/banned:

```
def active_for_authentication?
  super && self.status != 'failed'
end
```

Comment: Yup, but in case a User fails Legal Test I have to give him an opportunity to take the test again (user will have 3 attempts to pass the test). I think I should use combination of Devise and Pundit policies

Comment: got it. adding the column `status` and writing some logic around should be enough then.